# Swagger - working with dynamic and static files

Tags: java, swagger

I have a spring boot application that makes use of a library, and both use swagger to generate documentation. Right now what I see when I access the swagger main page is a combo box with two options, one for the main application, and another one for the library. So far so good. The problem is that we decided to serve the documentation of the main application in a static file, but the library should remain as it is now, annotation-based.

Does anyone know how to mix a static file and an annotation-based one?

If it is not possible, I can generate the yaml file of the library and serve it as a static one as well, it should be ok, but in this case, how can I serve both files and show them in a combo so the users can choose which one they want to visualize?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks under the hood? It is quite difficult to point to a direction if you do not afford much details on how your application setup looks like already.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Yes, I'm using spring boot.